# How to avoid this circular import?

Tags: python, import, circular-reference

Asset variable must be declared from mother file (this is a simplified version).

**File cannot be merged.**

This mother file works :

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf

data=yf.Ticker("^NDX")
dataHist= data.history(interval="1d",start= dt.date.today()-dt.timedelta(days = 50) ,end= dt.date.today()-dt.timedelta(days = 0))

df = pd.DataFrame(dataHist[["Open","High","Low","Close"]])

import child_file

if __name__=="__main__":
    
    df["expo"] = child_file.exponential_moving_average
    
    print(df)
```

With this child file :

```
import pandas as pd

import parent_file

exponential_moving_average = pd.Series.ewm(parent_file.df["Close"],span=12).mean()
```

But if replace in mother file:

```
data=yf.Ticker("^NDX")
```

by this to be able to choose the asset :

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    asset = "^"+str(input()).upper()
data=yf.Ticker(asset)
```

It says

```
NameError: name 'asset' is not defined
```

(from child file point of view)

**How do i reorganize the code ?**

I tried a lot this has went for several days now

Comment: The entire point of `if __name__=="__main__"` is to contain code that **doesn't** execute when imported by another module.    Off the top of my head, it looks like the `data=yf.Ticker(asset)` line should also be indented underneath that if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not defining anything new or implementing any modular functions in your child file, I would suggest moving that to the parent file and deleting the child file.

However, if you so choose to maintain the two, you should

1. load dataFrame in your child file, but not your parent file.

You could potentially define a function in your child file that takes parameters required for loading your ticker data, and call that function from your parent file.

Edit:

I would write a function in your child file.

```
def moving_average(close_price): 
    return pd.Series.ewm(close_price, span=12).mean()
```

Comment: Asset variable must be declared from mother file (this is a simplified version), mother file is planning to have several child file

Comment: I would write a function in your child file.

def moving_average(close_prcie):
    return pd.Series.ewm(close_price, span=12).mean()

Comment: This works man, thanks 
And i dont need to do a circular import anymore much cleaner